# Search Functionality using Cartodb API

Tags: javascript, html, carto

I posted a  similar question about this a month or so ago and I was still in early stages of researching the problem thus not to many results came from it .After some time and effort I have come close to having my desired results. The goal is to have a search box that queries the table on my cartodb account and then results get sent back to the API. The code below works as described however that is because I have the value of the form hard coded. I did this to show that the function is correct and that the value does get passed on the the query.My problem thought is once i delete the hard coded value and try to type the text in, the  query results  on my Console  are blank.  So some where the value is getting dropped and I am not quite sure where. (I posted the whole code so that you can copy and paste to see the results...If desired)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Bounds example | CartoDB.js</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 95%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
 </style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet"    
      href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
<form action="#" method="post"  id="form">
    <input type="Text" name="userInput" id="test" value="ARNOLD RD"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="processFormData();" />
</form>
<!-- include cartodb.js library -->
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
<script>
  var layer;
  function main() {
    var map = L.map('map', { 
      zoomControl: false,
      center: [39.104181025785,-76.77140813181],
      zoom: 8
    });
    L.tileLayer('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/landplanner.map-\
       yp548gxo/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '<a href="http://mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">w/ 
     Mapbox</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    var layerUrl = 'http://johnmann111.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/fe164544-1c6a-
     11e3-af5f-5404a6a69006/viz.json';
    var layerOptions = {
      query: "SELECT * FROM {{table_name}} order by st_ymax(the_geom) desc",
      }

    function processFormData() {
    var input = document.getElementById('test').value;
    return input;
    }

    var myVar = processFormData();

    cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl, layerOptions)
    .on('done', function(layer) {
     map.addLayer(layer);
      setTimeout(function() {
        var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'johnmann111' });
        sql.getBounds("select * From aps_intersection where sec_rte Like '" + myVar + 
        "'").done(function(bounds) {
          map.fitBounds(bounds)
        });
      }, 2000);

    }).on('error', function() {
      cartodb.log.log("some error occurred");
    });

  }
  window.onload = main;
     </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out what was wrong with my code. 
SetTimeout only allows for one call, so i changed it to setInterval which does mulitple calls.

```
       function processFormData() {
        var input = document.getElementById('test').value;
         return input;
       }



     cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl, layerOptions)
      .on('done', function(layer) {
       map.addLayer(layer);
    setInterval(function() {
        var myVar = processFormData();
      var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'johnmann111' });
       sql.getBounds("select * From aps_intersection where sec_rte Like '" + myVar + 
       "'").done(function(bounds) {
       map.fitBounds(bounds)
      });
     }, 2000);
```